# Python Pandas Referencing Value in Multiindex Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, reference, multi-index

I have a multi-index dataframe with 1 column of data as follows:

```
                                  Weight
Ticker       date
ABC    2017-03-31 00:00:00        .00292
  ...       ...                       ...
```

I am referencing it as follows:

```
df.loc[(ticker,date),'Weight']
```

Instead of getting a value returned I'm getting this:

```
Ticker     date
ABC       2017-03-31     0.00292
```

instead of this:

```
0.00292
```

When I type `info()` it tells me I have a MultiIndex Dataframe with 1 data column.

I have data/code like this all throughout a script - but with this particular data (which looks clean) and this syntax it isn't working.

Strangely, when I do this:

```
df.loc[(ticker,date),'Weight'][0]
```

it returns

```
0.00292
```

But when I try to iterate through the df it seems to revert to

```
Ticker     date
ABC       2017-03-31     0.00292
```

And then I can't perform other operations.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem. `df.loc[(ticker,date),'Weight']` gives me `0.00292`

Comment: This is crazy.  I have several other multilevel indices that work properly. i should add that I created this df by using  `.copy()` on another.  and then I set the multilevel index.  And Spyder TELLS me it's a multilevel index....

Comment: try `.item()` :)

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely crazy.  Finally resolved by just using [0] at the end as noted above.  All available information points to the data in a regular dataframe that is correctly changed to a multi indexed dataframe. No data irregularities either.  Very weird